# if statement based on 3 different conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let us say I have a list of user roles , and there are 3 conditions where the user will be redirected to a page and it is based on settings value.

I have my code below , is that the cleanest way to do it ?. I am looking for advice. Thanks.

The conditions are

```
settings  - if settings has value and user roles not equal to broker -> navigate to properties page
settings  - if settings has no value and user role is equal to broker -> navigate to navigate to transaction page
settings  - if settings has no value and user role not equal to broker -> navigate to index page
```

#user roles
["admin, "broker", "manager" , "consultant"]

#code

```
this.userService.updateUserProfileSettings(oldUserProfile)
      .subscribe(
        res =>{            
          const forwardToPage = localStorage.getItem('forwardToPage');
          if(settings && role !== 'Broker'){
           this.route.navigateByUrl('/properties');
          }else if (!settings && role === 'Broker') {
       this.route.navigateByUrl('/transactions');
          }else{
            this.route.navigateByUrl('/index');
          }
        },
```

Comment: Your current condition will trigger "/index" if setting has value and user role is equal to broker

Comment: `settings` does not exist in your code... what is settings ?

Comment: what to do `if settings has value and user role is equal to broker` ? you forget this case !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much can be improved in this condition, except your "else" will be true if `setting` has value and `role` = `broker`, which is not part of your list of conditions. This maybe a little less congested and account of that missing condition:

```
this.userService.updateUserProfileSettings(oldUserProfile)
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      const forwardToPage = localStorage.getItem('forwardToPage');
      let url = "/error"; //default
      if (!settings)
      {
        url = role != 'Broker' ? "/index" : "/transactions";
      }
      else if (role != "Broker")
      {
        url = "/properties";
      }
      
      this.route.navigateByUrl(url);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that
(but you forget the case of `settings has value and user role is equal to broker`)

```js
const target = ['/index','/properties','/transactions','??index' ] 

function test ( settings,role )
  {
  let condition = (settings ? 1 : 0) + (role === 'Broker' ? 2 : 0)
  console.log (`settings is ${settings} and role is ${role} ==>  ${target[condition]}` )
  }

test( true,  'not Broker' )
test( false, 'Broker'     )
test( false, 'not Broker' )
test( true, 'Broker' )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```